# SQL Server stored procedure in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-core

I created the application in ASP.NET core which needs to get details from SQL Server through a stored procedure.

Here is my code

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
connection.Open();

SqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lat", "31.77987");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lng", "-106.4119");

cmd.Connection = connection;
cmd.CommandText = "sp_Procedure";

var r = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

When I run this code, I got an error

> The server is attempting to use a feature that is not supported on this platform

If I missed out anything please correct me.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: How about sharing the code of your procedure? That is almost certainly where the problem is originating. Also, what version of sql server are you using?

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2012. Due to some security issue i am unable to share my procedure.